# MongoDB auto type conversion

Tags: mongodb

Is it possible to automatically convert a valid ISO string to a date on inserting into a MongoDB.

I mean automatically without building a wrapper for inserts?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. I'm doing it this way with C#:

```
if (!DateTime.TryParse(str, null, DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal, out DateTime start))
    throw new ArgumentException("Invalid field Start '" + str + "'");
Start = start;
```